# Javascript onclick fires without click using it in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using AJAX to get one of my database tables. I'm trying to improve it by making an update table function after the button is pressed.

```
success: function(result) {
    for( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++ ) {
        document.getElementById('tableT').innerHTML +=
            "<tr>" +
                "<td>"+result[i]['id']+"</td>" +
                "<td>"+result[i]['terminalId']+"</td>" +
                "<td>"+result[i]['departmentId']+"</td>" +
                "<td>"+result[i]['profileId']+"</td>" +
                "<td>"+result[i]['created']+"</td>" +
                "<td>"+result[i]['modified']+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+"<div style='margin-bottom:10px; text-align: center;'>"+
                "<a class='btn btn-info edit-btn' data-toggle='modal' onclick='"+updApplication(result[i]['id'])+"' data-target='#myModal-44' title='Edit'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a>"+
                    "</div>"+"</td>"+
            "</tr>";

    }
},
```

Why do I get alerts with all my ids without even pressing a button?

```
function updApplication(id){
    alert(id);
};
```

Comment: you are calling the function each time, it should be a string not a function call if you don't want to loop to call it...`onclick='updApplication(result["+i+"]['id'])'`

Comment: When writing about alerts it would be helpful to know the text of the alert messages. But I'm sure *depperm* points in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in quotes, now you're calling `updApplication()` function in every loop iteration, your code should be like  :

```
..data-toggle='modal' onclick='updApplication("+result[i]['id']+")' data-target='#myModa..
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You get alerts because you are actually calling the function when building your markup.

Try defining the `onclick` with your function as a string.

```
"onclick=\"updApplication(" + result[i]['id'] + ")\"..."
```

Comment: There will be no access to the local `result` variable when the `onclick` takes place. And `id` should be in quotes, or just use `.id`.

Comment: Yep, looks better, keeping in mind that if the `id` is a string, it'll need to be wrapped in quotes in the argument position. If it's a number, then no problem.